# Does Django 1.6 support the IGNORABLE_404_URLS setting?

Tags: python, django, django-1.6

I am getting hammered by script kiddies. The IGNORABLE_404_URLS setting doesn't seem to be working.

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#ignorable-404-urls), the IGNORABLE_404_URLS is a list of regular expressions and BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware is required for it to work.

Here is an example of my setting.

```
IGNORABLE_404_URLS = (
    r'^wp-login$',
)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs do say:

> List of **compiled** regular expression objects

Try:

```
IGNORABLE_404_URLS = (
    re.compile(r'^wp-login$'),
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I also just noticed that SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS was also deprecated in 1.6. I'm guessing this was the main issue but I removed the SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS setting anyways.